# Android studio automatically closes after opening

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android studio is closing automatically. I have tried setting up JAVA_HOME in environment variables.But it doesn't work at all.Any problem with my SDK or java version?Currently I have both 32bit and 64bit of java JDK 8..But it doesn't work for both.Can someone resolve it soon..I have been trying it for 2 days..

Comment: Please tell what is your OS and  what you are doing to open Android Studio. Have you tried to open it from a terminal to see if it displays some sort of error message?

Comment: It's working. Thanks for answering..

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall android studio and download the .exe installer file for it [here](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/4.2.0.24/android-studio-ide-202.7322048-windows.exe) and try reinstalling it, if it doesn't still fix the issue, tell me again, else mark the answer as correct.

Comment: It really works.. I did the same many a times but I don't know why it happened yesterday..thanks a lot.

Comment: Please mark my answer correct if it worked. I think there must be a configuration compatibility problem.